# How to retrieve data from Firebase in android RealTimeDatabase to update on the basis of regid

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from my Realtime Database server[image] so that I can update values based on the reg-id (stored this as a child string, not as Auth) I have saved for the user.

I have done this till now

```
    private void updateDatatoFirebase(String regid, String doctor_name, String city,String speciality) {
    Map<String, Object> update=new HashMap<>();
    update.put("doctor",doctor_name);
    update.put("city",city);
    update.put("speciality",speciality);

    DatabaseReference dbref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    dbref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                key = snapshot.getKey();


                if(checkid.equalsIgnoreCase(regid))
                {
                    dbref.updateChildren(update);
                    Toast.makeText(need_help.this, "Data in Database updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else
                    Toast.makeText(need_help.this, "No such id found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
           
            Toast.makeText(need_help.this, "Fail to add data " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

to update but it won't update
and I have saved data like this

```
private void addDatatoFirebase(String regid, String doctor_name, String city,String speciality) {
    
    root=firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("RegId").child(regid);
    HashMap<String, String> usermap=new HashMap<>();
    usermap.put("doctor",doctor_name);
    usermap.put("city",city);
    usermap.put("speciality",speciality);
    root.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
           
            root.push().setValue(usermap);

            
            Toast.makeText(need_help.this, "Data in Database updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
          
            Toast.makeText(need_help.this, "Fail to add data " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: To understand better, do you need to update all children that exist under the `1234` node? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes I want to edit all the children under the 1234 node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to update all children under a particular node, for instance, `1234`, you have to pass to the following method, `1234` as the first argument:

```
private void updateDatatoFirebase(String regid, String doctor_name, String city,String speciality) {
    Map<String, Object> update=new HashMap<>();
    update.put("doctor",doctor_name);
    update.put("city",city);
    update.put("speciality",speciality);

    DatabaseReference dbref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    dbref.child("RegId").child(regid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                ds.getRef().updateChildren(update).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(need_help.this, "Data in Database updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(need_help.this, "Failed with an error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(need_help.this, "Fail to add data " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Things to notice:

- I have added two extra calls `.child("RegId")` and `.child(regid)` call right after the root reference.
- I have used the `ds` to call `getRef()` and then `.updateChildren(update)`.
- I have attached a listener to see if something goes wrong when updating the children under `1234`.

Comment: Thank You so much for helping me. You have been a lifesaver! But I wanted to know what exactly I was doing wrong. For example, some things I notice straight away are I call a reference to FirebaseDatabase as                                                                   
                FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();           
 instead of                                                                                                     
      DatabaseReference dbref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Comment: Yes, that was one, and the omission of the call to `.child("RegId").child(regid)`.